# Remove extra line separators below List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've created a simple `List` as below, but there are extra separators below it.

```
List {
  Text("Item 1")
  Text("Item 2")
  Text("Item 3")
}
```

Result:

[image]

I've tried embedding the List inside a `VStack` and adding `Spacer()` like below code but it's not working properly. It removes about half of the empty cells.

```
VStack{
  List {
    Text("Item 1")
    Text("Item 2")
    Text("Item 3")
  }
  Spacer()
}
```

How would I remove these extra separators in SwiftUI?

Comment: In UIKit you fix this by setting the table view's `footerView` to an empty view. Maybe SwiftUI supports a List footer.

Answer (score 36):

## iOS 14:

iOS 14 doesn't show extra separators **below the list** by default and to removing **all separators**, you need to use a `LazyVStack` inside a `ScrollView` instead. (because iOS is **NOT** supporting appearance for SwiftUI lists anymore).

[image: LazyVStack Preview]

---

## iOS 13:

> ⚠️ This method is deprecated and it's not working from iOS 14

#### No need for `Section` or `.grouped` style!

There is a `UITableView` behind SwiftUI's `List` for iOS 13. So to remove

#### - Extra separators (below the list):

you need a `tableFooterView` and to remove.
**Note that** iOS 14 doesn't show extra separators below the list by default.

#### - All separators (including the actual ones):

you need `separatorStyle` to be `.none`

```
init() {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { 
        // iOS 14 doesn't have extra separators below the list by default.
    } else {
        // To remove only extra separators below the list:
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    // To remove all separators including the actual ones:
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
}

var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
}
```

**Note that** it eliminates all tables/lists's separators. So you can toggle it in a methods like `onAppear()` or etc. as you wish.

Comment: At this time, neither "tableFooterView" nor "separatorStyle" is reachable.

Comment: For IOS 14, when we used LazyVStack we loose the selection and reordering features of a list. So, it's not a valid solution for all of the cases.

Comment: "OS 14 doesn't show extra separators below the list by default." Does this mean there is a way to show separators below the list? Because I have the exact opposite scenario where I would like to to show empty rows.

Answer (score 21):

It's not a perfect solution, but you could use a ScrollView, where each cell is created using a ForEach call, and the dividers are created using Divider().

Edit: I spoke with Apple engineers at WWDC about this. They have heard lots of feedback regarding removing/changing dividers. However, for now my above answer is their recommendation.

Comment: any hints how to add some nice animation for reloading? when data will change?

Comment: @Lifeplus that's a good point. For now, I'd use one of the other answers which uses a List, and the ability to manipulate separators should be added soon.

Comment: Not bad solution, but we need to not forgot about "reusable" view (for tableview / list). if we use scrollview as solution, we automatically up memory usage.

Comment: Also it's not an option if we need "Edit" functionality. Like ability to delete/move the rows.

Comment: @RustamG you're right. Frankly, I'm a little disappointed with the bare minimum customization for standard elements provided by SwiftUI so far. I get that it's new, but if it's the future for Apple platforms, you'd think they'd have a huge push behind it.

Answer (score 18):

This is for iOS 13 builds only.

Use `onAppear` modify a separator style through `UITableView` and restore to the initial state with `onDisappear`

```
List {}
.onAppear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none }
.onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine }
```

Answer (score 14):

Not an ideal solution, but you can make the list style `.grouped` by `.listStyle(.grouped)` which removes any empty cells that may come below.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a white rectangle as a footer and with 0 EdgeInsets worked for me:

```swift
struct Footer: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
}

struct Timeline : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(footer: Footer()) {
                Text("Item 1")
                Text("Item 2")
                Text("Item 3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is it also adds a Header and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## iOS 13 builds only:

You can add this, for remove separator.

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
```

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way.

```
List {
         Section(footer: Text(""))) {
                Text("One")
                Text("Two")
                Text("Three")
            }
     }
```

Instead of the Text view in the footer, you can create your own. 
Note -I tried EmptyView() but that doesn't actually remove the redundant separators.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to remove the extra dividers this adds to the top and bottom of the list?

Comment: As I mentioned you can create own and use it instead of Text, maybe a view with 1 pt height.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of doing that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
                Text("One")
                Text("Two")
                Text("Three")
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header"), footer: Text("Footer")) {
                Text("One")
                Text("Two")
                Text("Three")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend grouped list style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to use the section, There's still a footer visible with this:

```
List {
    Section(footer: Text("")) {
        Text("My text")
    }
    EmptyView()
}
```

[image]

I came up with a hacky way to hide footer in case you don't have any section:

```
List {
    Text("Item 1")
    Text("Item 2")

    // Adding empty section with footer
    Section(footer:
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .background(Color(.systemBackground))){EmptyView()}
            .padding(.horizontal, -15)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reason, I had this problem in `tableView` even after iOS14, even though the answer above that there will be no longer extra separator lines in default.

The method I use to solve it is to set `footerView` to vacant `UIView`, as in that same answer.

```
your_tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```