# How to remove List selection indicator and separator in SwiftUI?

Tags: list, selection, swiftui, separator

I code a List in a ScrollView, when I selected a List cell to translate to another view and return back, the cell selected indicator did not disappear after selecting.
I hope after selected the list cell, the selected indicator should be disappear.

I debugged, I found that the ScrollView has some problems when it worked with List.If no ScrollView, the list selection behavior is all right, if plus the ScrollView outside the list, the problem become.

The other problem is How to remove the List Separator.

Thank you for your help!!!

```
@State var valueData: [String] = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Cake"]
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                DietListView(valueData: self.$valueData)
                DietListView(valueData: self.$valueData)
                .padding()


            }

        }
        .frame(width: 352)
    }

}

struct DietListView: View {
    @Binding var valueData: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.valueData, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DietItemDetailView()) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(item)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("100")
                        }
                    }

                }
                .onDelete { index in
                    self.valueData.remove(at: index.first!)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 300)

        }
        .frame(width: 352, height: 350)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}
```

the problem just like this:
[image: List selection problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (SwiftUI Beta 5) you can't customise `List` very much changing, for example, the divider style. What you can do, depending on your needs, is to use a `ScrollView` with `ForEach` and give the cell the style you want. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var valueData: [String] = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Cake"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    DietListView(valueData: self.$valueData)
                    DietListView(valueData: self.$valueData)
                    .padding()


                }

            }
            .frame(width: 352)
        }

    }
}

struct DietListView: View {
    @Binding var valueData: [String]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(self.valueData, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("ciao")) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(item)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("100")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .padding(10)
                    }

                }
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
        }
        .frame(width: 352, height: 350)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Also, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498261/1291872

**EDIT:** you can use `onDelete`, `onMove` and `onInsert` only within a `List`. If you want to let users delete a row in a `ScrollView` you must implement something yourself. Take a look at the code below for a simple (pretty ugly) example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var valueData: [String] = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Cake"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    DietListView(valueData: self.$valueData)
                    DietListView(valueData: self.$valueData)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 352)
        }
    }
}
struct DietListView: View {
    @Binding var valueData: [String]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(self.valueData.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("ciao")) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(self.valueData[idx])
                            Spacer()
                            Text("100")
                                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                            Button(action: {
                                self.valueData.remove(at: idx)
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
                        .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
        }
        .frame(width: 352, height: 350)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: First, thank you so much. Then how to use the modifier like "onDelete" to work with the ScrollView. I have tried, but it didn't work like List behavior. It's the primary reason I have to use List.

Comment: @Alexweng Take a look at my edit. There's a thing I'd like to point out: I don't know if it's exactly what you want, but since you are passing the same array to all the DietListView, deleting an element from a DietListView actually deletes that element for all the other DietListView as well.

Comment: thank you so much. Your edit is I want. The upside code is just demo for description my problem. Actually I just want something like a To-Do List, such as the list cell could be deleted, moved, and others. Your edit gives me an inspiration.